# Scala modify element in queue

Tags: scala

I have a Queue of class Component:

```
class Component(node:Integer, start:Integer, c_size:Integer);

var queue = Queue[Component]();
```

I would like to access an element from the queue by value and modify it, somehow like this:

```
if(queue.contains(neighbour)) {
   queue[neighbour].c_size += 1;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need a Queue here?

Comment: Yes, I am using it in some other places as well.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit strange to do this with a Queue, because in theory you only want to access first and/or last element of a queue. May be a ListMap would be a better idea?

I have tried something in console (Scala 2.11.7):

```
scala> case class Component(node:Int, start:Int, size:Int)
defined class Component
scala> val lm = ListMap[Int,Component]()
lm: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component] = Map()
scala> def addToList(lm:ListMap[Int,Component], element:Component) =
     | lm += (lm.size -> element)
addToList: (lm: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component], element: Component)scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component]

scala> addToList(lm , Component(1,2,3))
res8: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component] = Map(0 -> Component(1,2,3))

scala> addToList(lm , Component(2,32,43))
res9: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component] = Map(1 -> Component(2,32,43), 0 -> Component(1,2,3))

scala> addToList(lm , Component(3,324,543))
res10: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component] = Map(2 -> Component(3,324,543), 0 -> Component(1,2,3), 1 -> Component(2,32,43))
scala> def upNeighbour(lm:ListMap[Int, Component], node:Int) = {
     | lm.withFilter({
     | case (k, v) => (v.node == node) }).map ({
     | case (k,v) => lm(k) = v.copy(node=v.node+1)})
     | }
upNeighbour: (lm: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component], node: Int)scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[Unit]
scala> upNeighbour(lm, 2)
res12: scala.collection.mutable.Iterable[Unit] = ArrayBuffer(())
scala> lm
res13: scala.collection.mutable.ListMap[Int,Component] = Map(1 -> Component(3,32,43), 0 -> Component(1,2,3), 2 -> Component(3,324,543))
```

Note: As you can see, modifying an element resulted in removing that element and inserting the other one, with the same key. Because the key is preserved, you can still iterate by the sorted version of keys and get the original order. I havent's checked if the behaviour is the same if you use var instead, though.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour can be achieved by using `map` and then "performing a check for equality".

One open question in this solution is if *all* elements that are equal to your criteria should be changed or only the *first* one.

Given example assumes all elements that fulfil the requirement should be changed.

## Example implementation

### Data

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

case class ReducedComponent(node:Int)

val example = Queue(1,2,3,4,3,1) map ReducedComponent
```

### Replacing by value: All occurences which have value

```
def replaceByValue(in: ReducedComponent) = example.map(c => if (c == in) c.copy(node = c.node +1) else c)
```

## Example in REPL

```
scala> replaceByValue(ReducedComponent(3))
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[ReducedComponent] = 
  Queue(ReducedComponent(1), ReducedComponent(2), ReducedComponent(4), ReducedComponent(4), ReducedComponent(4), ReducedComponent(1))
```